# How big is the threat of Desktop Linux malware?

Tags: linux, malware

Most malware one hears about on the news seems to fit into one of two categories:

- Windows viruses, trojans, rootkits etc.
- Linux *server* "worms", backdoors and similar

How big is the threat of classical Windows Desktop-style malware (i.e. viruses, keyloggers, trojans) for a Linux Desktop user sitting behind a router making direct attacks on the machine unfeasible, meaning that the likely avenues of infection would be browser exploits, email attachments etc.?

Has such malware been encountered "in the wild" on a significant scale? Do malware distributors target Desktop Linux users? How much protection do Linux' built-in security features provide from an escalation of the attack through all levels of the system?

Answer (score 4):

First, let's dispel any thought that Linux is somehow magically immune: [classic file infectors](http://all.net/books/virus/index.html), [trojan horses](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf) and rootkits all existed on Unix well before Windows became prominent. I believe there's a number of reasons why classical Windows Desktop-style malware will not get a foothold in the population of Linux desktops. I don't believe any single reason is enough, but taken all together, they add up to something like "herd immunity".

1. Linux has a tradition of separating "user" and "administrator" roles. It's not mandatory, and it's not impervious, but it's there.
2. Linux has more sensible file permissions, read/write/execute, and the user/group/other separation, along with setuid. This also is just a small thing, and if you read E[xperiences with Viruses on Unix Systems](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/tdvirus.pdf) by Tom Duff, you see that it doesn't work at all in interactive, 80s-style multi-user systems.
3. Linux has a very fractured hardware and software base. I run ancient 2003-2006 era hardware at home.  It still works very well. But it means that malware writers can't count on anything as far as hardware goes. Same for software: there's almost always between 3 and 10 candidates for any particular niche. Email clients abound, and each has a loyal user base. If that's not enough variation, every distro compiles their own, so no consistent "build" is present on a critical mass of desktops. Also, versions of everything, including the kernel, change far faster than Microsoft changes things. For any particular candidate software in a given niche, many versions exist in the wild. It's also not that uncommon to compile whatever yourself, so you've essentially got an uninfectable version of whatever utility.
4. Linux has a better tradition of separating data from executable files. `/usr/share` contains documentation, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` contain executables, `/etc` contains configuration. Everything gets different ownership and permissions. Again, like file permissions, not mandatory and not solid, but it exists.
5. Linux does not have the array of special cases that Windows has. From multiple-rooted file systems ('C:' vs 'D:') to specially, magic files names that appear in any directory ('AUX', 'CON', etc) to "long file name support", Windows requires a good deal more care when programming. These special cases also provide niches to hide files, or get things to execute.
6. Magic file name extensions. This one has always boggled my mind - who thought it was a good idea to make a file executable by part of its name? Also, who thought that hiding the extension from a user is a good idea?  How many viruses/phishing attacks came about because you can execute a file named "Threesome.jpg.exe", but the file browser *hides* the ".exe" part? Yes, another small thing, and yes, you can configure it away, but nobody does. For a long time, Microsoft didn't enumerate what extensions made a file executable, so every once in a while, a new kind of file-infector would crop up.
7. Linux has far better documentation. Yes, plenty of "Head First", "For Dummies" and somewhat more advanced titles exist for Windows. But you've always got the source for Linux. Anyone can verify that some particular documentation is accurate. Nothing gets handed down from On High. I'm thinking of officially-sanctioned things like the [Inside Windows NT series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1572316772), which seems like it's gone through 3 authors and 6 or 7 editions. All that fluff, yet nobody has officially documented the NT native API. Just so you don't think that I'm hating on Microsoft, Oracle has the same sort of problem, as did DEC in the past.

Some of these are social (traditions), some are at least a little technical (file extensions) but have a social component. There may be more, but I think any two or three of the differences above make Linux users into a less vulnerable population.

Comment: "_Linux does not have the array of special cases that Windows has_" Seriously? From device files to fifos, there are many things that you can open for reading or writing, that will behave differently and block at different times. Symlinks are hard links are special. `/dev/tmp` like devices are special and their semantic has changed. `#!` executables are special, they are not first class programs, as don't run directly (the interpreter replaces the script). Running a SETUID program is special; and SETUID programming is very tricking. Really nix semantics are awful from a security point of view!

Comment: "_Linux has a tradition of separating "user" and "administrator" roles_" Like NT. The Windows 3 and Windows 95 series did not, but **MS killed Windows** and only kept the Windows NT system. Many incompetent user/admin (on a personal computer) come from Windows and do not understand the "depth" of security gained by the user/admin separation.

Comment: "_Linux has far better documentation_" Linux has terrible documentation. Sometimes semantics are only described in dev mailing list. gcc has issues (see: `asm`). C has issues (see: aliasing). OTOH, MS sometimes has ambiguous or even contradicting documentation for essential semantic issues (memory consistency issues come to mind).

Comment: "_For a long time, Microsoft didn't enumerate what extensions made a file executable,_" True; I bet very few people can enumerate these from the top of their mind (I sure can't). The extension hiding thing is perhaps the most notable misfeature of Windows.

Comment: @curiousguy - great. Write your own explanation of why Linux has so much more malware than Windows. Oh, wait...

Comment: Un*x/linux is horrible from a security POV. But Windows is worse. Also, nix has many stupid admins, but Windows usually comes with an inane user who sees himself as a know-it-all because he can do a couple of simple tasks. GNU/linux distros come with lots of software to do many basic tasks. Windows computer often don't. Also, **most malware just aren't ported to linux**.

Answer (score 1):

> Has such malware been encountered "in the wild" on a significant scale?

Nothing like what we have seen on Windows. [Bliss](http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/~axel/bliss/) is probably the most well-known. Viruses for Linux tend to have a very short life (this is a good article for that: http://librenix.com/?inode=21). I'd say the main reasons for this short life would be a) the virus doesn't get to run as root, and b) most of the software you use is open source, so exploits get found quickly and patched rapidly.

> Do malware distributors target Desktop Linux users?

Hard to answer definitively of course. I'd say 'no' mainly because:

- hard to do because of the security/user set up of Linux
- not as much market share (excluding apache/servers)
- (my opinion only) but I could see it as 'friendly-fire' among malware-writing groups (honor among theives? I have no idea.) I only say this because you'd have to have a deep understanding of Linux to create a serious exploit... and those people probably love it and would rather write a patch than try and make a quick buck off of it.

> How much protection do Linux' built-in security features provide from an escalation of the attack through all levels of the system?

A lot. This is what made pre-Vista Windows such a security nightmare (or dream depending on your perspective). Besides the built-in stuff that I mentioned, there are still security tools for Linux like [Antiviruses] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Anti-virus_applications)